# I need one specific character (bold omega). Can't seem to get it to work

Tags: fonts, bold, stix2

I'm using TexShop/Tex Live 2021 on macOS 12.4. I would like to produce a particular character in my output pdf file. This character is called "U+03C9 GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA" in Font Book. I want the bold version which is included in the font STIXGeneral-Bold. I also attach a screenshot of this character. I have been reading online for hours and tried dozens of proposed solutions, but I have not been successful yet. I would be OK with producing my entire document using STIX fonts and using/or XeLaTeX if necessary, although I have always used pdflatex in the past. If someone could provide a MWE example that produces this exact character in math mode, I would be very grateful.[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As David Carlisle brought up, the `lcgreekalpha` package option enables `\mathbf{\omega}` in `stix`, as well as `stix2`.  I’ll leave the rest of my answer up in case someone else needs an alternative.

Switching to `unicode-math` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX cuts the Gordian knot of technical debt to the last century.  In this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
{\textomega} {\textbf{\textomega}}
\(\symup{\omega}\) \(\symbfup{\omega}\) 
\(\boldsymbol{\symup{\omega}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: XITS sample]

The XITS font family by Khaled Hosny is a fork of STIX that does have them.  In this case, the first symbol is from XITS-Regular, the second from XITS-Bold in text mode, the third from XITS Math Regular, the fourth from the mathematical alphanumeric symbols block of XITS Math Regular, and the fifth from XITS Math Bold.

Instead of loading `\textalpha` to enable the `\textomega` command, you could instead use `\mupomega` from `unicode-math`.

If you’re forced to use PDFTeX, you can either use the bold math version of `\omega`, or substitute the upright bold omega of a compatible text font, such as Tempora:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\newcommand\mbfomega{\text{\usefont{LGR}{Tempora-TLF}{b}{n}\textomega}}

\begin{document}
\[ \boldsymbol{\omega} \, \mbfomega
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX and Tempora sample]

A third possibility, with many other packages, is to load one of the few upright OML-encoded fonts as your `\mathbf` alphabet, either with `isomath` or with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and `\SetMathAlphabet` directly.  However, legacy TeX supports only sixteen math alphabets, and I believe `stix` uses them all already.

Comment: the 8bit type1 stix2 and stix1 fonts do have this character.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `stix2-type1` does, but I don’t see it in [the documentation for `stix`](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf). What did I miss?

Comment: doc is same (as is the package) the example in my answer works with `stix` replacing `stix2`  see row 2 on page 3 of the link you give, showing `\mathbf` applies to Greek

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

with pdftex you can use `stix2` with an option so that lowercase Greek follows the math alphabet:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lcgreekalpha]{stix2}

\begin{document}

$\omega \mathbf{\omega}$
\end{document}
```